# Downgrade from PHP 7.1 to 7.0 for Laravel project

Tags: xampp, laravel-5.3, php-7

I work with an application in Laravel, facing a problem that cant be solved unless downgrading. So I downgrade my XAMPP form 7.1.14 to 7.0.30

After install it, I open my project and run composer update

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - This package requires php 7.0.30 but your PHP version (7.1.14) does not satisfy that requirement.

The version doesn't change and the project not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `XAMPP` and re-install with your suitable version. In past, I have faced same problem. I had problem for upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just lower the laravel version in composer.json file, it will automatically use necessary version of PHP